# Java String Array Iteration: Is there any way to make this simpler?

Tags: java, arrays, string, iteration

Good day,

I'm new to Java and have been practicing with **Nested Loop** iterations. I was wondering if there is any simpler way on how to do this? Especially on the part where I had to put this **[j+1]**.

```
String[][] entry = {{"010", "John", "Male", "21"},
                {"011", "Mary", "Female", "25"},
                {"012", "Joseph", "Male", "24"},
                {"013", "Peter", "Male", "22"}};


for ( int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {

    for ( int j = 0; j < entry[i].length;) {
        System.out.print("ID: " + entry[i][j] + "\n");
        System.out.print("Name: " + entry[i][j+1] + "\n");
        System.out.print("Gender: " + entry[i][j+2] + "\n");
        System.out.print("Age: " + entry[i][j+3] + "\n");
        System.out.println(""); 
        break;
    }           
}
```

Expected output is like this:

ID: 010
Name: John
Gender: Male
Age: 21

ID: 011
Name: Mary
Gender: Female
Age: 25

ID: 012
Name: Joseph
Gender: Male
Age: 24

ID: 013
Name: Peter
Gender: Male
Age: 22

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, this kind of data structure is better represented by writing a custom class. Writing a custom class is now much easier in Java 16 with the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... You can delete your inner loop, as you are breaking in the first iteration, hence not looping at all.

```
String[][] entry = { {"010", "John", "Male", "21"},
                     {"011", "Mary", "Female", "25"},
                     {"012", "Joseph", "Male", "24"},
                     {"013", "Peter", "Male", "22"} };


for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("ID: " + entry[i][0] + "\n");
    System.out.print("Name: " + entry[i][1] + "\n");
    System.out.print("Gender: " + entry[i][2] + "\n");
    System.out.print("Age: " + entry[i][3] + "\n");
    System.out.println("");       
}
```

EDIT: If nested loop is mandatory, you can achieve the same output like so:

```
String[] type = { "ID", "Name", "Gender", "Age" };

String[][] entry = { {"010", "John", "Male", "21"},
                     {"011", "Mary", "Female", "25"},
                     {"012", "Joseph", "Male", "24"},
                     {"013", "Peter", "Male", "22"} };


for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < entry[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(type[j] + ": " + entry[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");       
}
```

But, I'd advise against this.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your prompt reply. Yes, that does work. However, I'm trying to use nested loop for this. Just edited that part, sorry.

Comment: Well, you can't use a nested loop without extracting the first bits (ID, Name, Gender, Age). See the updated answer for a crude way of doing it, which, I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @shoshinsha You aren't using a real nested loop. You start an inner loop, but you assume that j == 0, and before the loop ends, you break out of it unconditionally. So the inner loop could just have been replaced with ``int j = 0;`` followed by your print statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
String[][] entry = {{"010", "John", "Male", "21"},
                {"011", "Mary", "Female", "25"},
                {"012", "Joseph", "Male", "24"},
                {"013", "Peter", "Male", "22"}};

String[] label = {"ID", "Name", "Gender", "Age"};

for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < entry[i].length;) {
        System.out.println(label[j] + ": " + entry[i][j]);
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

I have removed the `break`.  It shouldn't have been present in the original code either.

It is better to use `println` than to append a newline.  (Appending `\n` is not portable.  The *correct* line separator to use is OS dependent.  There ways to append the correct line separator, but it is simpler to let `println` take care of it.)

We could also use `printf` rather than concatenating the strings explicitly.